# Use OAuth2 in Spring Security without Spring boot support

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I built an web application without using Sprint boot support. The front-end is AngularJS. The back-end is Spring MVC restful API. Now I need use OAuth2 and Spring Security configure to protect the resource and authenticate user's credential.

I've spend over 2 days to research how to integrate. But all the examples show the ease of building Spring boot web security project and add OAuth2 dependency ([here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v) and [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/10/spring-boot-oauth2-security.html)).

The problem is that my existed project did use Spring Boot. And I'm confusing with ton of oauth2 and spring security configurations.

Please save my days. Thanks all!

Comment: Spring restful API is a Spring-MVC?

Comment: Yes. I will correct the question

Comment: Checkout the two "official" sampes "sparklr" and "tonr": https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2

Comment: Sorry but it's hard to understand

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs

Comment: https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2014/12/21/implementing-oauth2-with-spring-security/